# WPF: Changing paths of all databindings

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to change all the databindings in a window when a user clicks on a button.
**Note: the following code is pseudo.**

Assuming we have a class called sensor:

```
public class Sensor : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public int HighVal {get; set;}
  public int LowVal {get; set;}
}
```

And the following model to which we bind:

```
public class SomeModel {
  public Sensor MovementSensor {get; set;}
  public Sensor TemperatureSensor {get; set;}
  public Sensor BarometerSensor {get; set;}
}
```

In my xaml, I would like to bind in the following way:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyModel.MovementSensor.HighVal}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyModel.BarometerSensor.HighVal}"/>
```

I would like to have a button (or something similar) that upon clicking, will change all databindings' path from HighVal to LowVal, e.g.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyModel.MovementSensor.LowVal}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyModel.BarometerSensor.LowVal}"/>
```

Is there an elegant way to perform this without iterating over all databindings in the window?

Thanks!

Comment: I would add a value called `DisplayValue`, and have the button toggle a property in the model that triggers if it returns `HighVal` or `LowVal`. That seems like the better MVVM way to do it than having logic like that in your View :)

Comment: @Rachel: That would cause multiple windows showing different parts of the model to be affected, but that is not what is needed. I need an option to actually change the current view only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a MultiBinding that is connected with the two values of the sensor and a third property to determine the current value:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Resources>
        <y:SensorValueConverter x:Key="SVC"></y:SensorValueConverter>
    </TextBlock.Resources>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SVC}">            
            <Binding Path="MyModel.BarometerSensor.HighVal" />
            <Binding Path="MyModel.BarometerSensor.LowVal" />
            <Binding Path="MyModel.BarometerSensor.SelectedVal" />    
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

In the Windows tag you specify the namespace of the converter, but you have to replace the "YOUR-PROJECTNAME" placeholder:

```
<Window x:Class="..."
        ...
        xmlns:y="clr-namespace:YOUR-PROJECTNAME">
```

I have extended the class Sensor by the property SelectedVal which stores the value that should be shown in the TextBox. Changing it to "High" or to "Low" will immediatly update the Binding of the TextBox.

```
public enum SelectedValue
{
    High,
    Low
}

public class Sensor : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       

    public int HighVal {get; set;}
    public int LowVal {get; set;}

    SelectedValue selval = SelectedValue.High;
    public SelectedValue SelectedVal
    {
        get
        {
            return selval;
        }
        set
        {
            selval = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedVal"));
        }
    }
}
```

And now the most important part, the ValueConverter for the Binding that will choose the right value depending on the state of SelectedVal (class `CultureInfo` is the System.Globalization namespace):

```
public class SensorValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {         
        SelectedValue val = (SelectedValue)values[2];

        if (val == SelectedValue.High)
        {
            return values[0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return values[1].ToString();
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
}
```

To change the selected value of the sensor, you need to modify the SelectedVal property:

```
MyModel.BarometerSensor.SelectedVal = SelectedValue.Low
```

**UPDATE:**
To assign the binding to many Elements, a style can be defined in a separate file (Styles.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:y="clr-namespace:YOUR-PROJECTNAME">

    <y:SensorValueConverter x:Key="SVC"></y:SensorValueConverter>
    <Style x:Key="ValStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Text">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SVC}">
                    <Binding Path="MyModel.BarometerSensor.HighVal" />
                    <Binding Path="MyModel.BarometerSensor.LowVal" />
                    <Binding Path="MyModel.BarometerSensor.SelectedVal" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

To use this Style from other windows put simply this line in the resources of the window:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
```

Finally you need to assign the created style to all TextBlocks that should display the values:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ValStyle}"></TextBlock>
```

For a sensor with only one property, you can create another style in Styles.xaml that has to be bound to only one property:

```
<Style x:Key="SpecialValStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Text">            
        <Binding Path="MyModel.BarometerSensor.HighVal" />
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
Several points that are problematic:
1. One window will affect another - e.g. if on one window the 'SelectedVal' will be changed to 'Low', it will affect other windows that display the same data.
2. Development clumsiness - my application consists of dozens of windows which show various sensors. I would need to change every xaml binding from the simple syntax shown in my question, to the one shown in your answer. 
How can we overcome these challenges?

Comment: Challenge 1 could be solved by placing "SelectedVal" in each window. Challenge 2: You could create a Style for the TextBox and place all the bindung stuff there. Then you will have to declare the bindings only once.

Comment: May I ask for an example of #2? How can I access (via a global style) the binding set in an individual textbox?
And yet another question: How would you treat the case of a 'SpecialSensor' who only has 'HighVal' and not 'LowVal'?
Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: I've put an example and an answer in my post. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I looked at it, but it doesn't really deal with the problem.
I would need something like a converter defined in styles.xaml, that multi-binds to: a. the SelectedVal of the window b. the original binding that the user will use on the specific textbox - in essence, the global converter should be global to every textbox the user can define; the user on his part should be able to write something like:
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ValStyle}" Text="{Binding TemperatureSensor}"/> **and** <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ValStyle}" Text="{Binding BarometricSensor}"/> (using the same converter)

Comment: I don't see another solution than defining a seprate style for each type of sensor. As only "HighVal" or "LowVal" change in the path this shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Sorry but that is impossible. There are tens of thousands of sensors, so defining a converter for each one is not an option.

Comment: Would the DataContext of the element be an option: `<TextBlock DataContext="MyModel.BarometerSensor" Style="{StaticResource ValStyle}" />`. In the Style the Path can be shortened to `Path="HighVal"`

Comment: +1 for the dedication, you answered all the original question @berlo I suggest either asking new question or what actually would be better trying one of the answers and the asking new question if something isn't clear enough

Comment: @alu: thank you very much for all your help. Changing the DataContext is not an option **in my case**, as there are several 'SensorCollections' (that all have the same sensors) that a user can pick from in the window, and that changes the DataContext of the whole window. _but_ as you provided a reasonable solution to the problem and have done above and beyond to try to help me, I am marking your answer as the answer to my question. Thanks again!